# AS3 Passing Variables to a function not working?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, gallery

I had written this code out using Adobe CS3 and have recently upgraded to CS5. I haven't touched this site in forever and the last time that I did it worked great. The problem is as follows.

type of page: gallery
problem: passing variables

this is the original code that worked last time I checked it but has since stopped working.

```
function onClick(e:MouseEvent):void
    {
            trace(e.currentTarget.name);
            loadPics(e.currentTarget.name);
    }
```

This is the onClick function. The great thing is that the trace spits out the correct path to the photo. The problem happens in the loadPics() function. As you can see I'm passing the same path (the one that prints to screen correctly) to the function. here's the code for the function, I apologize if it's a bit messy.

```
function loadPics(pic):void
{
    photoLoader.source = pic;
    photoLoader.y = 10;
    photoLoader.x = 10;
    loaderHolder.addChild(photoLoader);
    //trace (pic.name) yields nothing
    //trace (photoLoader.source.name) yields nothing
    //trace (photoLoader.name) yields the default instanceXX name
    if(photoLoader.source.width > photoLoader.source.height)
    {
            trace("landscape");
    }
    else if(photoLoader.source.width < photoLoader.source.height)
    {
    trace("portrait");
    }
    else
    {
            trace("fail");
    }

    //draw loader background
    loaderHolder.graphics.beginFill(0xffffff, 1);
    loaderHolder.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, photoLoader.source.width + 20,                photoLoader.source.height + 20);
    loaderHolder.graphics.endFill();
    loaderHolder.x = 230;
    loaderHolder.y = 70;
    this.addChild(loaderHolder);
}
```

Please shed some light on this issue. My thumbnails load great, and all the paths are correct. The error that spits out when I click a thumbnail is this

> ReferenceError: Error #1069: Property name not found on String and there is no default value.
>       at portfolio_fla::MainTimeline/loadPics()
>       at MethodInfo-379()

So I'm deducing that the correct file isn't being loaded because no file is being loaded at all. Is there a disconnect between the argument I'm passing and the fact that loadPic isn't reading it as a string? Please help!

Oops almost forgot here are my declarations for the holders

```
var loaderHolder:Sprite = new Sprite();
var photoLoader:UILoader = new UILoader();
```

This is the error the debugger outputs when I load the movie

> Attempting to launch and connect to Player using URL C:\Documents and Settings\Brodie\Desktop\stephTsai\portfolio.swf
>   [SWF] C:\Documents and Settings\Brodie\Desktop\stephTsai\portfolio.swf - 426245 bytes after decompression

This is the error the debugger outputs when I click a thumbnail button

> gallery/large/test1.jpg
>   ReferenceError: Error #1069: Property width not found on String and there is no default value.
>       at portfolio_fla::MainTimeline/loadPics()[portfolio_fla.MainTimeline::frame1:45]
>       at Function/portfolio_fla:MainTimeline/loadThumbs/portfolio_fla:displayThumbs/portfolio_fla:onClick()[portfolio_fla.MainTimeline::frame1:163]

That first part 'gallery/large/test1.jpg' is the program tracing the path at the end of the loadThumbs() function... I'm so lost and I apologize if the code/methodology is weird but I haven't touched actionscript in forever.

(EDIT-----------------------------------------------------------------)
I've done some investigating...

If I add this in - this.addChild(photoLoader) into the code than it loads a very small version of the picture onto the screen when i click. I can also access the height and width of the photoLoader item. So I'm guessing that what's screwing it up is that in this section:

```
if(photoLoader.source.width > photoLoader.source.height)
{
        trace("landscape");
}
else if(photoLoader.source.width < photoLoader.source.height)
{
trace("portrait");
}
else
{
        trace("fail");
}
```

and

```
loaderHolder.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, photoLoader.source.width + 20,              photoLoader.source.height + 20);
```

The program is trying to get the height and width of the string not the picture. Is there a different sytax I should be using or a step I should be taking in order to load picture in correctly before executing the rest of the function?

Comment: Please turn on the debugger and post the **full error messages**. Nobody can help without that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

photoLoader.source is of type string. That's is what the runtime is complaining, when it tries to fetch width on the source property. What you need to use is photoLoader.width and photoLoader.height.

BTW, I think the code won't get correct width and height until the resource (the picture) actually gets loaded. So, you'd probably need to wait for Event.COMPLETE before checking on height and width of photoLoader.

Comment: Hey thanks for the comment. I've got the pictures to load, but they are loading in at a very scaled down version. Any ideas? I guess, what I want to do/need the program to do is to use the native width/length of the photos to load them into the gallery.

Comment: As I had said, you'd need to listen for Event.COMPLETE on photoLoader. Just add listener after setting photoLoader.source and then check for width and height in the eventHandler. That should work.

Comment: I did, thank you. I also had to change the this.addChild to just loader.load() so that I could unload and reload new pictures easier. Thank you for the comment and pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

this is more like a comment not an answer, but I can't post comments (have no idea why). Anyway, user985138 is right. For example:
- onClick is a handler of CLICK event, but where did you attach it
- function loadPics(pic):void - pic should have a type

I suggest you to click Ctrl+Shift+F12 in Flash, go to Flash tab, click on Settings... button of Script value and tick String and Warning modes. Then to compile and investigate.

Answer (score 0):

I cant see where you get the Error in the code. Are you running the traces?  You should really start to type your variables. For instance, you are passing a `String` into the function loadPics:
 `loadPics(e.currentTarget.name);`

Then you are trying to access the variable name of the `String`. That makes no sense.

Comment: I went ahead and added the extra function as well as the debugger information in. I appreciate your feedback. The idea behind it is that I load the path to the picture into loadPics and then make that the source of pictureHolder. All the random tracing that's commented out of there was just to see if the variable was being passed correctly at all. I realize it's dumb to try and access something like e.currentTarget.name.name << which is what I think you're saying is dumb. I agree, but I didn't know what else to look at.